# ACCESS Join Without Distinct Identifiers

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables which do not have distinct identifiers for joining.  However, Table1 has a field (Milestone) that contains a text string containing a format of 999ABCD.  Table2 has a Subject field that also contains this information; however, it is located in random locations as part of a title within the Subject field for the records.

Is there a way to join the two tables (Table1.Milestone to Table2.Subject) based on the value in Table1.Milestone and searching for matching text within Table2.Subject?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work or not but might get you started in the right direction:

```
select * from Table1 T1
join Table2 T2
on T2.Subject LIKE '%' + T1.Milestone + '%'
```

I wouldn't recommend doing a join like this though even if it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Access but I've gotten this to work for you in MS SQL.  If you can find a similar function to CHARINDEX in Access this will work for you:

Setup:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (milestone varchar(20))
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (subj varchar(1000), details varchar(1000))

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES ('999ABCD')
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES ('999XYZ')

INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES ('Subject is 999ABCD', 'I should join only to 999ABCX')
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES ('Subject 999XYZ is me', 'I should join only to 999xyz')
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES ('Subject zzzzz is me', 'Nobody gets me')
```

Actual Query:

```
SELECT *
from @table1 t1
JOIN @table2 t2 ON CHARINDEX(milestone, subj) > 0
```

Here is the output:

```
milestone   subj    details
999ABCD Subject is 999ABCD  I should join only to 999ABCX
999XYZ  Subject 999XYZ is me    I should join only to 999xyz
```

Hope that helps!

Dave

Comment: Needless to say, I'm not advising you ever join this way!  Just wanted to help solve your problem.